# Can a route be created for a variable that is defined in a view's loop?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hyperlink, routes

I have a route that works for my "thing"'s show view. This object is nested. This is the working route:

```
match 'parents/:parent_id/childs/:id/thing' => 'childs#thing', :as => :thing
```

My problem is that I want to have this link appear one level up, in an index of these objects. The link appears in a loop and when I use the :thing symbol for the link it says it has no route. Now I know what is wrong is that it's not getting the specific ID for the object in each iteration of the loop. But I don't know how to fix this. So basically I think what I am looking for is:

```
match 'parents/:parent_id/childs/(way to pass loop id goes here)/thing' => 'childs#thing', :as => :thing
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give the name you want to the parameter in the route declaration, for example `:index`

```
match 'parents/:parent_id/childs/:index/thing' => 'childs#thing', :as => :thing
```

Next, in the `ChildController`, you get the index value in `params[:index]`

```
def thing
  index = params[:index]
  # Example: find item by index using their creation date
  child = Child.order("created_at ASC").offset(index).limit(1).first

end
```

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with finding things by index. Could you explain this more? Is "index" in the controller a function used in the view or is it the placeholder variable in the route?

Comment: @Nathan `params[:index]` is the value set in the calling url (for example in 2 in the url http://example.com/parents/4/childs/2/thing). Its signification is yours... I've added un example in my answer: get the n-th child when sorted by creation date

Comment: Thanks I figured it out. I had been using :thing in the link view itself (which worked for some reason) but I should have been doing thing_path. The specific link worked as thing_path(@parent, @child)